# How to add new line on date formatted cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling to figure out a way how to format a Google Sheets cell in a particular way.

I need the cell to have date formatting (to have the dropdown date picker) and the date has to be formatted like this: `Dayofweek, (new line) dd.mm.yyyy.`

So for example:

```
Wednesday,

15.03.2017.
```

I can't figure out how to add the new line part:
[image: Google Sheets Date Formatting Example]

`Format -> Text wrapping -> Wrap` doesn't work for some reason. Do Google Sheets have a new line character, or perhaps it could be done using a particular function?

Answer (score 0):

try using script:

```
function setFormat() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  range.setNumberFormat('dddd,dd.mm\nyyyy');
 }
```

`\n` is a new line before year `yyyy`

Comment: It initially works, however after a short while (probably when the page finishes loading) the formatting gets reset for some reason.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. May be I could help you if you told me what the reason of getting reset of formatting.